# how to select values of vector 2 only when the values of vector 1 is greater than 0

Tags: matlab

Let's say that I have two vectors:

```
V1 = [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1]
```

and vector

```
V2 = [23 24 23 45 46 2 3 48 49 50 24 23 24 24 47 46]
```

how it can be created an vector output V3 (as below) where: if the value of Vector V1= 0 then then corresponding vales of  V3 = Nan, if V1 =1 than V3 = V2 .

```
V3 = [NaN NaN NaN 45 46 NaN NaN 48 49 50 NaN NaN NaN NaN 47 46]
```

Thank you in advance 
DM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise `V3` as `V2` then replace the indices of `V3` for which corresponding indices of `V1` have zeros with `NaN` using logical indexing.

```
V3 = V2;
V3(~V1) = NaN;
```

Comment: @D_Marini Of course it works. I was trying to show you how you can find both zero and nonzero elements for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) to find the indices of nonzero elements in V1.

Your inputs:

```
V1 = [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1];
V2 = [23 24 23 45 46 2 3 48 49 50 24 23 24 24 47 46];
```

Creating vector V3:

```
V3 = V1;

%Logical indexing for adding NaN.
V3(~V1) = NaN;

%Find indexes for non-zero V1.
indx = find(V1);

%Use indexes for filling V3 with respective values in V2.
V3(indx) = V2(indx);
```

Output V3:

```
V3 = [NaN   NaN   NaN    45    46   NaN   NaN    48    49    50   NaN   NaN     NaN   NaN    47    46]
```

For more information on how to use logicals for array indexing read the [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1).

Comment: thank you, that works ok. Meanwhile I was trying the following loop:        for i = 1:length(V1)
  if V1(i) == 0   
     V3(i) = NaN;
  else
    V3(i) = V2(i)  
    
  end
end                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 which also worked and output the same results.

Comment: There's no need to use a loop in this situation. You can perform these operations in Matlab using indexing only.